# ERROR: require() of ES Module not allowed

Tags: npm, rollup

### Background

I'm making a [library](https://github.com/airman5573/json-generator).

I tried to set up rollup so that users who use commonjs method and those who use esm can
use my library.

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "mockito",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "description": "let's make mock data easy!",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": "./dist/commonjs/bundle.js",
      "import": "./dist/esm/bundle.mjs"
    }
  },
  "main": "./dist/commonjs/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && rollup -c rollup.config.js",
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nanoid": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^3.2.3"
  },
}
```

```js
// rollup.config.js

export default [
  {
    input: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
      format: "cjs",
      file: "./dist/commonjs/bundle.js",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  },
  {
    input: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
      format: "es",
      file: "./dist/esm/bundle.mjs",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  },
];
```

Below is the result of the user downloading this library.

```
// node_modules

mockito
 ┣ dist
 ┃ ┣ commonjs
 ┃ ┃ ┣ bundle.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ bundle.js.map
 ┃ ┗ esm
 ┃ ┃ ┣ bundle.mjs
 ┃ ┃ ┗ bundle.mjs.map
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ data
 ┃ ┣ mocks
 ┃ ┣ utils
 ┃ ┣ constants.js
 ┃ ┣ generator.js
 ┃ ┣ index.js
 ┣ package.json
 ┗ rollup.config.js
```

I can import mockito module like this.

```js
import { generate } from 'mockito';

it works!
```

### Problem

But not working with `require('mockito')`;

Error message is this.

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module  
 .../node_modules/mockito/dist/commonjs/bundle.js from .../mockito-commonjs-webpack/src/index.js not supported.  
bundle.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a   
.js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module"   
which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.  
Instead rename bundle.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code   
to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules,   
or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /Users/yoon/Desktop/mockito-test/mockito-commonjs- 
 webpack/node_modules/mockito/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).  

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yoon/Desktop/mockito-test/mockito-commonjs-webpack/src/index.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

How to fix this ?

Should I change the "type": "module" to "commonjs" ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this problem is that nanoid v4 support only esm!

So I downgrade to v3.

Here is the [issue of nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/365)